# SQL Server query to get users and related roles listed on one line

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to get the output of all SQL Server logins (SQL 2005+) and their server roles, but for every login I need the roles listed on one line, for example:

```
HOSTNAME   USERNAME    DESC           ROLES
server     sa          SQL_LOGIN      sysadmin
server     john        SQL_LOGIN      dbcreator,securityadmin
server     DOMAIN\jack WINDOWS_LOGIN  diskadmin,setupadmin,dbcreator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should meet your expectations:

```
SELECT sp.name,
       sp.type_desc,
       (
        SELECT sp2.name + ',' AS [text()] 
        FROM sys.server_role_members srm as rolename
             LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals sp2 ON srm.role_principal_id = sp2.principal_id
        WHERE srm.member_principal_id = sp.principal_id FOR XML PATH ('')
       )    
FROM
sys.server_principals sp
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding [SQL string concatenation](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) logic on dbagley's proposal, I prepared following SELECT statement

```
;with cte as (
SELECT  
    sp1.[name] USERNAME
  , sp1.type_desc [DESC]
  , sp2.[name] ROLES
FROM  sys.server_principals sp1 
  JOIN sys.server_role_members srm 
    ON sp1.principal_id = srm.member_principal_id 
  JOIN sys.server_principals sp2 
    ON srm.role_principal_id = sp2.principal_id 
)
select distinct
    USERNAME,
    [DESC],
    STUFF(
        (
        SELECT
          ',' + ROLES
        FROM cte
        WHERE cte.USERNAME = t.USERNAME
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) As ROLES
from cte t
```

[image]

Comment: Nice job of taking it to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2026/tables-and-views-for-auditing-sql-server-logins/

```
SELECT  
    sp1.[name] AS 'login' 
  , sp2.[name] AS 'role' 
FROM  sys.server_principals sp1 
  JOIN sys.server_role_members srm 
    ON sp1.principal_id = srm.member_principal_id 
  JOIN sys.server_principals sp2 
    ON srm.role_principal_id = sp2.principal_id
```

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem.. have for the same sql server login account one single line with all roles listed. this list one line for each role a sql server login has

Comment: I understand now that you were more concerned about concatenating the roles as in the answer posted by @Eralper.